# Apache POI : I want to add subversion to file while creating excel file from java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to maintain file SubVersion to Excel file using POI whenever the user downloads the file. Is there any method to control subversion of excel file ?

```
try {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

    //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

    //Get first sheet from the workbook
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
    Iterator<row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        //For each row, iterate through each columns
        Iterator<cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    file.close();
    FileOutputStream out = 
        new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: use svn if you manintain sub versioning.

Comment: In java how can i use SVN ? user exports the excel and modifies it and uploads so i want to maintain Subversions.

Comment: your source and destination will be the same for file. correct? like user import from xyz location and upload to xyz location.

Comment: No from db will write data to excel and user modifies it and uploads back. Then that data again matched with db and updated accordingly. For this purpose i need to have hidden value like version while creating file.

Comment: Have your upload code check the file into SVN?